# Mule 4 repeatable stream processing

Tags: csv, stream, mule

I want a read a CSV file from SFTP of **~8gb**.
what is the best way to stream the CSV file also do transformation parallel?
can we do streaming as well as transformation in parallel?
If so how can we make sure the data required for transformation is available in the stream?
**Note: I am using Mule 4.1.2 runtime.**
any help on this would be great.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is default behavior. File connector provides stream as default. Transform transforms stream and provides transformed stream as default.

If you have time you can watch video here [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-l3G3zu1594&t=1s) ;)

If you want to do multiple transformations - do them in the same flow - one by one. It is the same stream only modified on each transformation.

What is the particular issue?